# Why is destructor never called?

Tags: c#

From what I understand the destructor is called when a class instance goes out of scope and the garbage collector makes a pass. In the code below the destructor is never called. What's going on?

```
while (true)
{
  var Thing1 = new Thing();
  await Task.Delay(100);
}

class Thing
{
  ~Thing()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Destructed");
  }
}
```

Comment: try calling garbage collector yourself.

Comment: — The garbage collector doesn’t make a pass. And why should it? Object destruction in C# is non-deterministic.

Comment: C# doesn't have destructors. It has finalizers, which unfortunately and confusingly borrow syntax from C++ while having completely different semantics. In general, finalizers are a "last resort"; they should never be *counted* on to be called -- that's what `IDisposable` and `using` are for.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers

Comment: [*"A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run at any point prior to program termination."*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Even more confusingly, finalizers *used* to be called "destructors" in C# (although .NET always used the "finalizer" term).

Answer (score -1):

With this code I managed to call the `Finalizer`. I guess, the garbage collector needs the heap to fill up to a certain point before it makes a pass.

```
while (true)
{
  var Thing1 = new Thing();
  await Task.Delay(100);
}

class Thing
{
  public List<int> List { get; } = new(1000000);

  ~Thing()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Destructed");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also call `GC.Collect`.